# Altering arrays of different dimensions to be broadcasted together

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, broadcast, dimensions

I am looking for a more optimized way to convert a (n,n) or (n,n,1) matrix to a (n,n,3) matrix. I start out with an (n,n,3), but my dimensions get reduced after I perform a sum over the second axis to (n,n). Essentially, I want to keep the original size of the array and have the second axis just repeated 3 times. The reason I need this is that I will later be broadcasting it with another (n,n,3) array, but they need the same dimensions.

My current method works, but does not seem elegant.

```
a0=np.random.random((n,n))
b=a.flatten().tolist()
a=np.array(zip(b,b,b))
a.shape=n,n,3
```

This setup has the desired result, but is clunky and hard to follow. Is there perhaps a way to go directly from an (n,n) to an (n,n,3) by duplicating the second index? or perhaps a way to not downsize the array to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`None` or `np.newaxis` is a common way of adding a dimension to an array.  `reshape` with (3,3,1) works just as well:

```
In [64]: arr=np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
In [65]: arr1 = arr[...,None]
In [66]: arr1.shape
Out[66]: (3, 3, 1)
```

`repeat` as function or method replicates this.

```
In [72]: arr2=arr1.repeat(3,axis=2)
In [73]: arr2.shape
Out[73]: (3, 3, 3)
In [74]: arr2[0,0,:]
Out[74]: array([0, 0, 0])
```

But you might not need to do this. With broadcasting a (3,3,1) works with a (3,3,3).

```
In [75]: (arr1+arr2).shape
Out[75]: (3, 3, 3)
```

In fact it will broadcast with a (3,) to produce (3,3,3).

```
In [77]: arr1+np.ones(3,int)
Out[77]: 
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2],
        ...
       [[7, 7, 7],
        [8, 8, 8],
        [9, 9, 9]]])
```

So `arr1+np.zeros(3,int)` is another way of expanding that (3,3,1) to (3,3,3).

The broadcasting rules are:

```
(3,3,1) + (3,) => (3,3,1) + (1,1,3) => (3,3,3)
```

broadcasting adds dimensions at the start as needed.

When you sum on an axis, you can keep the original number of dimensions with a parameter:

```
In [78]: arr2.sum(axis=2).shape
Out[78]: (3, 3)
In [79]: arr2.sum(axis=2, keepdims=True).shape
Out[79]: (3, 3, 1)
```

This is handy if you want to subtract the mean from an array along any dimension:

```
arr2-arr2.mean(axis=2, keepdims=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can firstly create a new axis (axis = 2) on `a` and then use `np.repeat` along this new axis:

```
np.repeat(a[:,:,None], 3, axis = 2)
```

Or another approach, flatten the array, repeat elements and then reshape:

```
np.repeat(a.ravel(), 3).reshape(n,n,3)
```

---

The result comparison:

```
import numpy as np
n = 4
a=np.random.random((n,n))
b=a.flatten().tolist()
a1=np.array(zip(b,b,b))
a1.shape=n,n,3
# a1 is the result from the original method

(np.repeat(a[:,:,None], 3, axis = 2) == a1).all()
# True

(np.repeat(a.ravel(), 3).reshape(4,4,3) == a1).all()
# True
```

---

Timing, use built-in `numpy.repeat` also shows a speed up:

```
import numpy as np
n = 4
a=np.random.random((n,n))
​
def rep():
    b=a.flatten().tolist()
    a1=np.array(zip(b,b,b))
    a1.shape=n,n,3

%timeit rep()
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 7.11 µs per loop

%timeit np.repeat(a[:,:,None], 3, axis = 2)
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.64 µs per loop

%timeit np.repeat(a.ravel(), 3).reshape(4,4,3)
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.9 µs per loop
```